# Cockney rhyming slang

Tags: slang

could you please help me to understand what does it mean?

> "crash, bass, sausage and mash, two kippers and a bonbon, a little
>   dab'll do ya"

and also:

> "Tiddly winky woo"

(I doubt if it means "drink" here)

[It's from this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhSNKJ_lcNU) at 11:56

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question can stay closed but it should be redone to point to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571187/what-does-this-bit-of-cockney-mean/571531#571531), which covers the entire bit including these parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**crash, bass, sausage and mash, two kippers and a bonbon** is just a more florid way of saying **crash, bang, wallop** meaning *after a short (often unexpected) period of tumult*. I've heard many variants over the years, never this exact combination, but each of the components. There is no internal syntax to the phrase, it's justified by its semblance to the *crash, bang, wallop* prototype and intended to be judged by its internal alliteration, punning, reference and so on. In this case, I guess he's conveying the chaos in getting home from work and ready for a night out.

**Tiddley Winky Woo** is being used just to mean "like so" or as a flourish like we might say *"ta-da"*. It's a reference to an old song. I'd not recommend a non-expert using the phrase these days as you could end up with a knuckle sandwich in the boat race, given later associations with homosexuality.

The thing to bear in mind is that this guy is mainly having fun with language to increase his appeal.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not going to use it anywhere except for subtitles to this show :) You've really helped me out!

Comment: +1 simply for the expression "a knuckle sandwich in the boat race".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not British, so I haven't got the foggiest notion about those expressions - save one:

"A little dab'll do ya," is from the advertising jingle for Brylcreem - a men's hair pomade. (1950's) The product was originally British, but it was world-renowned. (As was the jingle)