# What does this bit of Cockney mean?

Tags: british-english, slang, dialects, sentence-meaning, rhymes

In the 2nd episode of the 3rd season of *Would I Lie To You?*, a fragment is shown from a 1985 episode of London Weekend Television's *The Six O'Clock Show*, with someone purporting to be a former [Teddy Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teddy_Boy) [saying the following](https://subsaga.com/bbc/comedy/would-i-lie-to-you/series-3/episode-2.amp.html):

> "1955, Saturday night, off to Tottenham Royal. So it was crash, bash, sausage an' mash, two kip[per]s and a bonbon, little dab will do you. Really so, on the Barnet. And the combination was Old Spice on the German, little bit of Old Spice, tiddly-winky-woo, with the Brylcreem, bee's knees."

It's [at the 6:33 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPJJ_4i26TI&t=393s).

Since they talk about a Cockney Bible afterwards, I assume this to be Cockney. And a rather contrived bit at that. And while I think I'm getting the general drift of what he's saying, I'm sorry I haven't a clue what he's actually saying.

From what I gather, in preparation to go out to [the Mecca Dance Hall in Tottenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecca_Dance_Hall,_Tottenham) on a Saturday night, he ate (sausage and mashed potatoes), then put on some Brylcreem (of which "a little dab will do you" was the advertising slogan) on the sides of his hair and Old Spice on his face, after which he fancied he looked good. But I'm probably missing half of it.

**What is he saying?**

---

*A comment pointed me to [another question about the same fragment](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236042/59244), that focused on a couple of phrases from that monologue. I'm interested in the meaning of the entire bit. For instance, "on the German" is not explained there.*

Comment: I believe 'Barnet' is Cockney rhyming slang for 'hair' (Barnet Fair). After those preparations he looked [the bee's knees](https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-bee-s-knees)

Comment: _German_ band is Cockney slang for hand...so Old Spice, [sprinkled] on the hand...

Comment: True Cockney rhyming slang, like Glaswegian (Glasgow) rhyming slang, is a code that one either knows or one doesn't, the whole intention being to drop the actual rhyme and to quote the non-rhyming part as a 'code'. 'Apples and pears' refers to stairs but I then drop the 'pears' and I 'go up the apples'. In both London and Glasgow the criminal fraternity used rhyming slang to speak of matters they did not wish to disclose. My now deceased mother was born within the sound of 'Bow Bells' [St Mary le Bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Mary-le-Bow) and we lived together in Glasgow in the 1960s.

Comment: Yea, I also don't think it makes sense to close this question as a duplicate of an off-topic question (on account of lacking research) when this question does meet the research requirement.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking, could he be describing his hairdo with the "two kips and a bonbon"? Or perhaps even the entire phrase? Because he goes straight into the "little dab will do you" from there.

Comment: @NigelJ Can you give me an example of Glaswegian rhyming slang? I have lived here for forty years and never heard of it. My contact with the criminal fraternity is limited to Taggart, but…

Comment: @David Andy Murray - curry ;
Corned beef - deif (deaf) ;
Alan Rough - guff (awful/ terrible) ;
Alan Wells - smells ;
Potted heid - deid (dead) ;
Arthur's Seat - feet ;
Auld Reekie - freaky ;
Berwick-upon-Tweed - heid (head) ;

Comment: @David [100 words that prove you are from Glasgow](https://www.glasgowtimes.co.uk/news/13272997.100-glaswegian-words-prove-glasgow/)

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks. The examples you give are interesting as those named after sportsmen are much more recent than Cockney rhyming slang. Andy Murray is contemporary, Alan Rough played for the *Jags* in the 70s and 80s, and Allan Wells won an Olympic gold in 1980.  I never said I was *from* Glasgow, I'm from the North of England but we used to *stay* in a tenement behind the *Botanics* — so *close*, *back green*, *factor*, *press*, *fish supper*, *The Citz*, *The Drum*, *Bankie*, *Parkheid* — and by the way, it's *Fair Fortnight*, although nobody goes "Doon the water" any more. Convinced?

Comment: @David My memories of Glasgow revolve around being treated to repeated experiences of the Scottish tawse, on one occasion when the whole class was belted in one go (and possibly boys joined again at the back of the queue just to be difficult). And then being accosted repeatedly outside and having to talk or fight my way out of it. But that was 1960s Glasgow and things have greatly changed. _Let Glasgow flourish by the Preaching of the Word and by the praising of His Name_ is still, I believe, the motto of the city : and still worth hoping for . . . . .

Comment: @NigelJ — I remember the tawse being abolished before my children could be subjected to it. Glasgow has its ups and downs, as it has had through the centuries, but I think it is managing to flourish. We certainly regard it as a ”Dear Green Place“.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a 1985 send-up of 1950s British [Teddy boys](https://allthatsinteresting.com/teddy-boy)' (≈[greasers'](https://subculture.fandom.com/wiki/Greaser)) personal hygiene as part of a general bit on [Brylcreem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brylcreem), although it doesn't seem like that whole episode of the *Six O'Clock Show* has been uploaded anywhere to allow the full context.

> 1955, Saturday night, off to Tottenham Royal.

An [old live music venue and dance hall](https://tottenham-summerhillroad.com/tottenham_royal.htm) that was playing rock and roll in the '50s and '60s, best known for hosting the [Dave Clark Five](https://rubbercityreview.com/2014/04/the-dave-clark-five-doin-the-tottenham-stomp/) later on.

> So it was crash, bash, sausage an' mash, two kip[per]s and a bonbon,

This bit is the messy part. Sure, it could theoretically be a hastily-slapped-together dinner of fish, potatoes, sausage, and chocolate. More likely, it would be about slipping in references to [piss](https://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/bangers_and_mash_1)[ing](https://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/sausage_and_mash_1_2) (via *[slash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slash)*) and/or [amorous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kipper) [strippers](https://phespirit.info/cockney/) past the censors. Still more likely, though, it's going through the exact same routine he's about to describe in nonsense mockney. At the same time he's saying these words (which appear in actual rhyming slang for entirely separate ideas), he's miming washing or scenting his hands and then applying a spot of pommade to his hair.

> little dab will do you.

Tagline for ['50s Brylcreem ads](http://headington.org.uk/adverts/beauty_toiletgoods.htm).

> Really so, on the Barnet.

[Hair](https://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/barnet_fair).

> And the combination was Old Spice

At the time, [still a cologne](https://www.historyofbranding.com/oldspice/) rather than an aftershave, deodorant, body wash, or whatever else they have out now.

> on the German,

[Hand(s)](https://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/German_band).

> little bit of Old Spice, tiddley-winkie-woo,

A period version of "[Skinnamarink](https://mudcat.org/thread.cfm?threadid=2749#11836)". Recorded in 1950 by [Guy Lombardo](https://www.discogs.com/Guy-Lombardo-And-His-Royal-Canadians-Where-Are-You-Gonna-Be-When-The-Moon-Shines-Tiddley-Winkie-Woo/release/7012326) and [Sammy Kaye](https://www.discogs.com/Swing-And-Sway-With-Sammy-Kaye-Roses-Tiddley-Winkie-Woo/master/820761) but seems to have also been [a postwar standard at Brighton](https://www.mybrightonandhove.org.uk/people/peopfolk/local_folk-7). Could be standing in for "How do you do?" as he's patting his cheeks and looking in the mirror or just a verbal flourish like *[ta-da](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/247124)* or *[o la la](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oh_l%C3%A0_l%C3%A0)*.

> with the Brylcreem, bee's knees."

[Great stuff](http://phrases.co.uk/meanings/the-bees-knees.html).

The most likely version of what he's saying is ([ooc](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OutOfCharacter)) that he's a posh twit mocking '50s working class young men and ([ic](https://roleplay.fandom.com/wiki/In_character)) that a splash of American cologne on the wrists and cheeks and a touch of British pommade in your hair was just the thing to have a good Saturday night on the town.

Comment: There are various other compilations of Cockney rhyming slang online. Here's [another from Rice University](https://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/usage/slang_cockney.html) that I didn't use in my answer. All such sources, though, will either be accurate but limited or expansive but inclusive of one-offs and minor variants without much guidance. (Many leave out the racial slurs, too, even though they were/are common in daily use.) You're probably best off sticking with the crowdsourced one even though its internal search is a bit nonexistent.

Comment: Re: the mockney in the first go-through, if you __really__ wanted it to mean something, it could be approximating something like _splish-splash, done in a flash_, _two_ [_dabs on the_] _face_ (via Mari-Lou A's Italian source [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1330)) _and_ [_up in the_] _hair_ (via _[bonney fair](https://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/bonney_fair)_) _some Brylcreem_. None of that is standard, though, and it's more likely he was just using common terms randomly (_kippers_ = _slippers_) through this part of the routine.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Could I persuade you to incorporate your two comments in the answer as extra information?

Answer (score 7):

So, from [the other question about this fragment](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236042/59244) and some helpful comments with unsourced but plausible explanations, I think it is as follows:

> "1955, Saturday night, off to Tottenham Royal."

As mentioned in the question, this was the name for [the Mecca Dance Hall in Tottenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecca_Dance_Hall,_Tottenham) at the time.

> "So it was: crash, bash, sausage an' mash, two kips and a bonbon,"

According to [the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236053/59244) on the other question, this means *crash, bang, wallop* or "after a short (often unexpected) period of tumult". Which means I was wrong about him eating.

> "[...] little dab will do you."

The advertising slogan for Brylcreem, as noted.

> "Really so, on the Barnet."

*Barnet -> Barnet Fair -> hair* So a bit of Cockney rhyming slang, meaning hair. Thanks to [Kate Bunting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571187/what-does-this-bit-of-cockney-mean?noredirect=1#comment1420989_571187).

> "And the combination was, Old Spice, on the German,"

Another bit of rhyming slang: *German -> German bands -> hands*, with thanks to [KillingTime](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571187/what-does-this-bit-of-cockney-mean?noredirect=1#comment1420996_571187). *Old Spice* being a brand of after shave.

> "[...] little bit of Old Spice, tiddly-winky-woo,"

Again according to [the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236053/59244), "like so" or "ta-dah!"

> "[...] with the Brylcreem, bee's knees."

Really, the cat's meow.

Comment: _Which means I was wrong about him eating._ - I don't think you were. I think "crash, bash" is referring to the hasty preparation of a quick meal (imagine the clatter of pots and pans) prior to dressing to go out. The meal being "sausage an' mash, two kips and a bonbon" - sausage and mash, two kippers and a dessert (bonbon -> sweet -> dessert).

Comment: I can't imagine anyone eating sausages and kippers at the same meal!

Comment: @KateBunting Possibly not in the real world but I can imagine this was for comic effect. That said, this is set in 1950s Britain where food rationing only ended the year before. Wartime shortages did lead to some odd food combinations hitting the table.

Comment: Are you sure that "crash, bash, sausage and mash" isn't a semi meaningless piece of rhyme, a bit like "bish, bash, bosh" and doesn't have anything to do with eating "bangers and mash" at all. I tend to think that sausage and mash doesn't isn't a quick meal to prepare and that eastenders tend to call sausages 'bangers' anyway (think of the music hall song  "give us a bash of the bangers and mash me muvver used to make".

Comment: @BoldBen - 'the music hall song "give us a bash of the bangers and mash me muvver used to make' again, mock Cockney. Rather than being music-hall, the song was written in 1960 for Peter Sellers and Sophia Loren.

Comment: @BoldBen ""crash, bash, sausage and mash" ... a semi meaningless piece of rhyme, a bit like "bish, bash, bosh" - absolutely this. Likewise the kippers and bonbons. The whole thing is a comedy piece of mock Cockney. It reminds me very much of Mr Bimmler - 'And eating I am lots of chips and fish and hole in the toads and Dundee cakes on Piccadilly Line, don't you know old chap, vot!'

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that the guy is recognisably (by accent) not a Cockney. He is mocking, caricaturing, or 'sending up' Cockneys by saying a stream of Cockney-sounding nonsense,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 'Oh, Mr Bimmler.  You do have us on!'

Comment: A kipper is a smoked herring, but apparently in cockney  **two kippers** was code for **a pair of  slippers** https://books.google.it/books?id=w_ohWEKQsqMC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%22two+kippers%22+cockney&source=bl&ots=ZCiS5hihK7&sig=ACfU3U3-iw07zBoWa1nWhMZqvlKYOgqVgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj28P_MpfLxAhXSzKQKHTolBZwQ6AEwDXoECCsQAw#v=onepage&q=%22two%20kippers%22%20cockney&f=false

Comment: I think it's more likely that **kipper** in Cockney was short for *kipper and plaice* (another type of fish) meaning **face** But why "2 kippers"? No idea!  https://books.google.it/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1330&lpg=PA1330&dq=kipper+cockney+rhyming&source=bl&ots=PGuzzD2R4J&sig=ACfU3U24ZYgdsmGNqKWICKyAsq4vPPwBtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGivqLqPLxAhWOvaQKHZ0rCD8Q6AEwJHoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=kipper%20cockney%20rhyming&f=false

Comment: @David I assumed everyone would know _Old Spice_, but I've edited it in just to be sure.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that would make sense, in a way, to have his slippers on when getting ready to go out.